# Need an opinion

Tags: criminal-law, alcohol

Ok, so pretty much long story short, I've been court ordered to AA, and have went three times thus far. It's been great also. They have given me this sheet till the end of next month, but I've already sweated on this thing, and made it look ugly. Do any of you think this will pose a problem? Particularly around the "location" part of the paper? 
Also the paper is bigger than this, it can hold up to 30 signatures.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The court will mainly want the signature, to prove you attended.

Don't screw that part up and you are fine. Keep the paper someplace safe.

Comment: I will, that's my word. I just dont want them to get the misunderstanding that I forged the document somehow with those nasty smears.

Comment: if the paper was pristine and all the signatures were nearly identical, you'd have a harder time convincing anyone that it is genuine. Paper gets smudged when it is used over such an extended period of time. That's a benefit for your situation.